# Export MySQL table rows as individual files (specifically JSON) in one go

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress

I have over 750 JSON files I need to create from a MySQL Database table.

It is the WordPress "wp_options" table, but this is a MySQL question.

The wp_options table has the following properties.

```
option_id, option_name, option_value, autoload
```

The "**option_name**" is to become the JSON file name.

I am fine if I "have to" rename each file name manually.

The "**option_value**" is to become the JSON data.

Is there a way I can do this more efficiently instead of creating an empty JSON file for each row and then copying the data base option_value to the JSON file?

My main concern is with 750 files to make I am a little weary I will miss something or double up on something, and this information has to be exact.

NOTE: I've read this stack article (which is the closest I could find) @ http://goo.gl/RnV5cf. But, It doesn't seem to be working as expected given the Wordpress wp_options values I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I needed to do this, and only needed to do it once, I'd probably just run a little php script locally.

Assuming you have grabbed this table as an array (here I've called it `$wp_options`), you could just iterate over it using [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and `fclose` to make your files. I've also assumed you want the files to have '.json' extensions but obviously you can strip that out.

```
foreach ($wp_options as $wpo) {
    $newFile = fopen($wpo['option_name'].'.json', 'w'); // w=write mode
    fwrite($newFile, json_encode($wpo['option_value']));
    fclose($newFile);
}
```

The above is untested, but I think that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need a local script:

```
<?php

// ...
foreach ($wp_options as $wp_option)
{
    $fileName = __DIR__ . '/' . $wp_option['option_name'] . '.json';
    file_put_contents($fileName, json_encode($wp_option['option_value']));
}
```

Comment: @d0ug7a5's solution would work too, but in PHP it's considered better form to use file_put_contents if all you're doing is fopen, fwrite, fclose